# A set of variables cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am having a problem when trying to use variables declared in another class. I can't figure out where is the problem. Can anyone please help?

This is my header file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "HELO.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef SMTPSERVER_H_INCLUDED
#define SMTPSERVER_H_INCLUDED

class SMTPServer
{
    private: bool newMessage;
    private: bool newRec;
    private: bool newSender;
    private: bool newData;

    public: SMTPServer();

    void send(HELO h1);
    void OriginalState();


};


#endif // SMTPSERVER_H_INCLUDED
```

The following is my cpp class. When I build the program, it is showing the error: Symbol 'newData' could not be resolved.

```
#include "SMTPServer.h"
#include "HELO.h"


SMTPServer::SMTPServer()
{
    newMessage = NULL;
    newRec = NULL;
    newSender = NULL;
    newData = NULL;
}

void send(HELO h1)
{

}

void OriginalState()
{
    newMessage = false;
    newRec = false;
    newSender = false;
    newData = false;
}
```

Comment: You wrote a *new* OriginalState() function, it isn't a match for SMTPServer::OriginalState().  Same problem with send().  What C++ book do you use?  Get another.

Comment: don't add "using namespace std;" to a header.

Comment: What's with the abundance of `private` keywords? This is not Java - use the keyword a single time before the entities you want to be private. Furthermore, all entities in classes are private by default, so you do not need it unless it is preceded by a `public` section. Also, the common convention is to place public members first, as these make up the interface that the readers of your header files care about primarily. The private members are implementation details, and better placed at the bottom (or hidden altogether using pimpl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use scope resolution operator `::` for function definitions:

```
void SMTPServer::OriginalState()
{
    newMessage = false;
    newRec = false;
    newSender = false;
    newData = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, I have this error:
make: *** [src/SMTPServer.o] Error 1 SMTP    C/C++ Problem

Comment: Which compiler are you using? On which IDE/OS?

Comment: @user3136756 Please post a new question relating to your other error. And don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I am using the compiler g++, ubuntu as the OS and Eclipse as the IDE

Comment: Do you have a `main()` function? For C++ applications to build, you need to define a `main()` function for the app to start. Google more about it.

Comment: Yes, I have a main function

Comment: As pointed out by @gturri below, make sure to also add SMTPServer:: to your send method.

Answer (score 1):

You should tell in your .cpp file that those methods belong to the SMTPServer class. ie:

```
void SMTPServer::send(HELO h1)
{

}

void SMTPServer::OriginalState()
{
  newMessage = false;
  newRec = false;
  newSender = false;
  newData = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `send` and `OriginalState` you're not using the scope resolution operator to denote that these are member function implementations; as-is, the compiler takes these as free functions.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the `SMTPServer::` thing for the last two function definitions